# Interaction of terms

Tags: r, classification

I'm fitting a model using R's `glm` and I would like to add a term with a particular interaction of variables:

$$
a\frac{K+0.6b}{T+b}
$$

where $K$ and $T$ are columns of data and $a$ and $b$ are constants to be fitted.

The overall model, then, looks like

$$
p=a\frac{K+0.6b}{T+b}+c_1C_1+c_2C_2+\cdots+c_\ell C_\ell
$$

where the $C_i$ are additional columns, the $c_i$ additional constants for the model to fit, and $\frac{1}{1+e^{-p}}$ is the estimate for the binary variable to be predicted.

What kind of analysis is needed to fit this model? Can it be done in R? I can use `offset` on $T$ and $K$ to ensure that they have no coefficients, and I can use `1` to represent a bare variable like $b$. But, having set $b$, how can I represent the $0.6b$ in the numerator?

Comment: You cannot use offset in the manner you describe unless you believe they were measured without error.

Comment: @DWin: Why? And what needs to be without error? K? T? p? Something else? Most of my variables are integral and are actually measured without error. Not all, of course.

Comment: Noting that 273.15/459.67 is pretty close to 0.6 are we discussing a data situation that involves two different measurements of temperature?

Comment: @DWin: No. Actually I have a number of different data sets which each have different associated constants; 0.6 is merely illustrative.

Comment: Regarding your question about using offsets, no coefficients are estimated for variables pointed to by offset terms. (That's the point.)

Comment: @DWin: Yes, that's why I'm using it. `T` and `K` have no coefficients, as you can see above. But the coefficient of the 1 in the denominator and the coefficient of the 0.6 in the numerator is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been better presented with a test data object but based on your comments (that change the question) you could try using `offset()` on K and T and `I()` on your proposed "one" variable:

```
> dat <- data.frame(Y=1:10, one=1, K=rnorm(10), T=rnorm(10))
> lm(Y~ I( ( offset(T)+0.6*one )/offset(K)+one), data=dat)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ I((offset(T) + 0.6 * one)/offset(K) + one), 
    data = dat)

Coefficients:
                               (Intercept)  I((offset(T) + 0.6 * one)/offset(K) + one)  
                                   5.42701                                     0.04631
```

That's probably not a complete answer, since it doesn't separately estimate a "b" coefficient for "one", but at least it estimates an "a". Now you can take the methods and see if `nls` is effective:

```
> nls(Y~  ( offset(T)+0.6*beta )/( offset(K)+beta), data=dat, start=list(beta=1)
+ )
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  Y ~ (offset(T) + 0.6 * beta)/(offset(K) + beta) 
   data:  dat 
 beta 
2.123 
 residual sum-of-squares: 317.8

Number of iterations to convergence: 12 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.603e-06
```

I don't think you can add another parameter to that model without creating a singular predictor matrix.

Comment: Thank you. This may be, as you say, not a complete answer but I will mark it as accepted since this is the closest I think I'll get. I'll study it and see if I can make it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This model is nonlinear in $b$, so unless you use a package that will fit generalized nonlinear models, this will force you to resort to fiddling about similar to what you mention (but moreso - and that will still leave you with a number of issues). Given $b$, it's linear in the rest.

The package *gnm* is an example of a package that can fit generalized nonlinear models in R, but I haven't really used it.

It is possible to sort of deal with it using a sequence of GLMs, maximizing the profile likelihood of $b$, but I'd only head down that path if I couldn't figure out how to get gnm to do it.

Comment: `gnm` seems like the right tool, but I can't see anything in its documentation as to how to use a variable twice in a formula. Am I missing something?

Comment: Charles, I'm sure there's no such syntactic limitation. Even if there were, writing $a \frac{K+0.6b}{T+b}$ as $a\left(0.6 + \frac{K - 0.6T}{T+b}\right)$ would work around it.

Comment: @whuber: Perhaps I'm missing something, or perhaps I'm just dense. But right now I don't name variables to be fitted, so there's no syntactic way for me to reuse them. `K` and `T` are in my model, I can name them directly as `mydataframe$K`. `a` and `b` are coefficients and as such have no names.

Comment: In a nonlinear model, you name the parameters as well as the variables. If possible it may help to first fit your model using nls (i.e. basically treating it as gaussian), or at least fitting *some* model in nls to get used to the way both variables and parameters are named in nonlinear models.